# Golang: Different AppEngine packages

Tags: go

What is the difference between this two AppEngine packages:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine

The only thing that stands out for me is that 2nd one has no Context type

Which one should someone use in developing an application?

Answer (score 3):

The "google.golang.org/appengine" packages work on both managed VMs and App Engine Classic. The "appengine" packages work on App Engine Classic only.

The "google.golang.org/appengine" packages use the [x/net/context](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context) package for passing context around.  The "appengine" packages use a context specific to those packages.

See https://github.com/golang/appengine#3-update-code-using-deprecated-removed-or-modified-apis for a list of differences in the APIs.