# Which Golang Packages to use for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-identity-toolkit

I recently started to explore the Google Identity Kit using golang on the App Engine. I was going off of the samples in the [googlesamples/identity-toolkit-go](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-go/blob/master/favweekday/favweekday.go). In looking at the code, I found some appengine packages for the following:

```
"google.golang.org/appengine"
"google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
```

For the GAE Golang application that I am working on, I use the GAE SDK to run the application using `goapp run`. However, in my code, I only reference

```
"appengine"
"appengine/datastore"
```

because this points to the golang src located in the extracted go appengine sdk.

**Do I need to be using the `google.golang.org` appengine packages instead?**

I only found this out after realizing that the appengine.Context that is expected by the identity kit methods did not match what I was using. I received this error

```
`cannot use c (type "appengine".Context) as type "golang.org/x/net/context".Context in argument to client.ValidateToken. "appengine".Context does not implement "golang.org/x/net/context".Context (missing Deadline method)`
```

despite me using `appengine.NewContext(r)` as the example explained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly import Golang appengine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271148/how-to-correctly-import-golang-appengine) and [Golang: Different AppEngine packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477505/golang-different-appengine-packages)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the `google.golang.org/appengine` packages if you can. They play nicer with the language, primarily because of the reason you mention (`context` is a `net/context`), and also because the libraries are newer and often have more features. In particular if you plan to use other Google services (like Google Cloud Storage) you'll have a much easier time using the newer libraries.

But they're also better because - since they're just regular, importable packages - they play nicer with the standard set of go tools: `goimports` for auto-formatting, `gocode` for autocomplete, etc..

However they are not entirely complete. There are some features [missing or deprecated](https://github.com/golang/appengine#3-update-code-using-deprecated-removed-or-modified-apis). In my experience it used to be that the major missing feature was the `aetest` package, which has since [been ported](https://github.com/golang/appengine/tree/master/aetest), so there's now very few reasons not to switch.